# Debugging Go via GDB with Vim (not gvim)

Tags: vim, go, ide, gdb

I am starting to get into Go, as it seems like an interesting language for web service development. I have historically created a new Ubuntu Server 14.04 instance for each of my language groups, and have kept the same principle for Go.

I have installed all the usual tools (Syntastic, YCM, NERDTree, ctags, you get the idea) and have got a great *writing* environment set up with some help from vim-go.

Now, I want to be able to get debugging set up in a similar way, using GDB, and am getting stuck on what the best tooling to use here is.

It seems as if Clewn is a great tool, but as I am using SSH to the development environment, I can't necessarily use gvim.

I basically just need a GDB tie-in to vim (not gvim). I am using vim 7.4 as per apt-get via ubuntu universe, and will be more than happy to build from source if some compatibility has not included.

Comment: Of course I did. I researched (and attempted without success) the Clewn family of GDB tools (Clewn, pyclewn, and vimGdb) as well as started using `gdb - tui` using GDB as per the [Go Guide](https://golang.org/doc/gdb).

Comment: As far as I understand, the Clewn tools instantiate a new gvim window piping though debugger information through a netbeans compatible link. This is where my problem lies methinks, as a new vim editor cannot simply be created in parallel over an SSH session, thus I am seeking advice.

Comment: "I have a problem, can you help me?" is not a valid question. "I have a problem, I tried this, this and that, they failed like this, like this and like that, can you help me?" is much better.

Comment: You can't use Clewn with Vim, only with GVim so you can forget about that entirely. Now, tell us what other setups you tried and how they failed and, maybe, someone will be able to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dbg.vim](https://github.com/yuratomo/dbg.vim).

Once the plugin installed, you can setup your breakpoints and use shortcuts to show value of variable under the cursor, etc.